# xsl:choose find the first position of elements but not the second

Tags: xslt

I would like to code an XSLT to convert an XML document to an XML-FO document, in order to generate a PDF.

This Image shows the [current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6wt6.png)

So my Table has 3 columns. In the first 4 lines the second and third columns are merged.

My XML document looks like this:

```
<WS-Standards>
    <tags>
        <tag  category = "parameters" > <!-- WS_Beer_Type -->
            <tag_name>WS_Beer_TypeX</tag_name> <!-- browsename -->
            <tag_number>30004</tag_number>
            <datatype>Unsigned32</datatype>
            <accessrights>RW</accessrights>
            <names>
                <name language="DE">Biersorte</name>
                <name language="EN">Beer Type</name>
            </names>
        </tag>

    </tags>
</WS-Standards>
```

My current XSLT document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="WS-Standards">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm"
                    margin="5mm 25mm 5mm 25mm" master-name="PageMaster">
                    <fo:region-body margin="20mm 0mm 20mm 0mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="tags"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tags">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tag"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag">
        <fo:block space-before="6pt" border-top="3pt solid green">
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="20%" border-style="solid"
                    border-width="1pt"/>
                <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="10%" border-style="solid"
                    border-width="1pt"/>
                <fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="70%" border-style="solid"
                    border-width="1pt"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag_name">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="1" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block> Tag Name </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="2" number-columns-spanned="2" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag_number">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="1" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block> Tag-Nummer </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="2" number-columns-spanned="2" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datatype">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="1" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block> Datentyp </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="2" number-columns-spanned="2" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="accessrights">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="1" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block> Zugriffsrechte </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="2" number-columns-spanned="2" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="names">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number(./name/position()) = 1">
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="1" border="1pt solid black">
                        <fo:block> Name </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="2" border="1pt solid black">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./name/@language"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="3" border="1pt solid black">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./name"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="1" border="1pt solid black">
                        <fo:block> NameXXX </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="2" border="1pt solid black">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./name/@language"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="3" border="1pt solid black">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./name"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="b">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question is about the names element for different languages.

So the first Line in the table of the names element looks like this:

```
-----------------------------
|Name   | DE | Biersorte    |
-----------------------------
```

But I`m missing the second line:

```
-----------------------------
|       | EN | beer type    |
-----------------------------
```

What am I doing wrong with the xsl:choose->when->otherwise function?

I would be happy about a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code is in a template matching `names`, but there is only one such element in your XSLT and so it will only be called once.

The expression `number(./name/position()) = 1` in this context is simply asking "For this `names` element, is there a `name` element in position 1", which is true, and so the `xsl:when` gets executed.

Your code really needs to be in a block where `name` is selected. Try this XSLT (which also removes the code duplication).

```
<xsl:template match="names">
    <xsl:for-each select="name">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="1" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block> 
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">Name</xsl:if>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="2" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@language"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="3" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: **Thanks** Tim for you explanation. :) I gues there is a tiny copy&Paste-error. Following code is working in my document: <xsl:if test="position() = 1">Name</xsl:if>